# CSS Selector Path - TestComplete Javascript Can't Click the Button

Tags: javascript, html, css-selectors, testcomplete

I have this piece of HTML code

[image]

I am using Testcomplete (Javascript) to target the button and try to click it. I think it is more about my CSS path/Javascript rather than TestComplete itself.

I tried this code and it works fine

```
var path2 = "#Table > div > table > tfoot > tr > th:last-child > span > div";
var z = Page.QuerySelector(path2);
z.Click();   // Works Fine
```

I also tried this one and it works fine

```
var path2 = "#Table > div > table > tfoot > tr > th:nth-child(7) > span > div";
var z = Page.QuerySelector(path2);
z.Click();  //Works Fine
```

But when I tried this one, it won't find and click the button

```
var path2 = "#Table > div > table > tfoot > tr";   // path to parent table
var z = Page.QuerySelector(path2);
var y = z.QuerySelector('div.blue'); // Look for the child from that parent with tag div and class blue
Log.message(y.getAttribute("class"));  // Will return "button blue w-icon footer-add"
y.Click();  // Will return Javascript Runtime Error. y.Click is not a function
```

I don't know why if I find the parent node first and then search for it's child , Javascript won't be able to find it and click it ?

Comment: Try `y[0].Click();`.

Comment: "I think it is more about my CSS path/Javascript rather than TestComplete itself." So what happens if you select it directly using `var path2 = "#Table > div > table > tfoot > tr div.blue";` instead? It seems odd that you'd leave that step out.

Comment: Thanks @ZakariaAcharki , but y[0] returns the same error

Comment: I'm guessing that `.Click()` is a method provided by Testcomplete? Native JS is `.click()` ([mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click)). Are you sure the JS for Testcomplete is loaded?

Comment: Thanks @BoltClock.  `var path2 = "#Table > div > table > tfoot > tr div.blue"; ` does work as well.  I didn't know that we can directly put `div.blue` after the parent path. Thanks for that.  But it is weird when I save it to a variable z, it won't work.

Comment: That's something. Now we know something is up with saving it to a variable. I don't use TestComplete so I can't help you further with diagnosing the problem, but I hope you manage to figure it out.

Comment: Thanks @LuudJacobs.  Both `.click()` and `Click()` work the same in TestComplete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this behavior can be explained by the following text from the [QuerySelector Method (Page Objects)](http://smartbear.com/viewarticle/81303/) TestComplete help topic.

> Result Value
>
> If a TestComplete web object matches the specified
>   selector, then the method returns this object.
>
> If there is no matching TestComplete test object, the method returns
>   the appropriate HTML object.

In your case, the first found object (`var z = Page.QuerySelector(path2);`) does not have a corresponding TestComplete object, so the native HTML object is returned. When you query the second object (`var y = z.QuerySelector('div.blue');`), you actually calls the native `QuerySelector` method and not the TestComplete one that can return a TestComplete object. So, you get the native object as a result of the second query as well even while there is a corresponding TestComplete object. The `Click` method is appended to TestComplete objects and you cannot use it when working with native HTML objects.

So, the only option in your case to break the long path into two pieces is seems to be this one:

```
  var path2 = "#Table > div > table";
  var z = Page.QuerySelector(path2);
  var y = z.QuerySelector('tfoot > tr > th:last-child > span > div.blue');
  Log.message(y.getAttribute("class"));
  y.Click();
```